# Can't run Next.js because of Node.js version

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm trying to create a Next.js app, but when I try to start the server, I receive this error:

> You are using Node.js 16.16.0. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.

However, when I type `nvm list`, only versions `20.11.0` and `18.17.0` are listed.

I have tried switching between both of those Node.js version, but I still got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched once again and tried running the project with `yarn dev`, which works just fine.

However, I would still appreciate if anyone could figure out, how to run it with `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while a go where it always to another version even though I changed and uninstalled it.

For me it fixed it when I switched in the package json from:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
  },
```

To:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node src/index.js",
  }
```

,

Maybe you need to change the directory and the location of the index.js
This way you are executing your program with the specific node.js version.

Comment: Well in my package.json i have this instead of index.js:
`"scripts": {  "start": "next start", },`
and in my src directory the main file is `page.tsx`.